# SHOUTcast streaming music and OpenX ads

Tags: javascript, streaming, facebook-javascript-sdk, openx

I have created a tab page app that streams music and displays banner ads via OpenX (approved by Facebook). The page that frames within Facebook is located here: https://www.mypchost.com/stream/

The problem I am encountering is that the banner ads will display properly OUTSIDE of Facebook, but not within the app itself (https://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPCHostcom/220325541429517?id=220325541429517&sk=app_484549871594370). What should happen is that both, the background should rotate at 30 second intervals, and the banners should change when the page is loaded; sometimes refreshing the page 3-6 times will make that happen, it varies.

I have tried using both JavaScript provided through OpenX and `iframe` code. Both will work OUTSIDE of Facebook - but never WITHIN it.

I have tried everything possible I can think of. I can set banners to be rotated manually using JavaScript, but that disallows the functionality of the OpenX ad server from rotating banners as then it isn't tied into the server, its manually coded onto the page.

Does anyone have any idea as to WHY this works OUTSIDE of Facebook and NOT inside? If you open one window with the outside version and one with the app within Facebook and refresh both, you will see different ads served. This is such a SIMPLE thing, but why in the world is it NOT WORKING!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is 'cause the delivery URL for OpenX isn't using your SSL URL.  Likely all you need to do to correct it is replace the http: with https: in your invocation code for the banner's zone.  There may be more to it but that's the gist.